# Appium simulator open in rosetta mode in m1 mac

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

My build IPA not included support for arm64 and its not support installed to normal simulator on m1 mac Xcode. Is there any way to specifiy to open in rosetta simulator on appium capabilities?

tried the simulators in Xcode 15 in m1 mac